# Как получить и работать с ID элемента, по которому кликнули (js)?

Tags: javascript

Есть пара картинок, с которыми нужно взаимодействовать по клику. Нужно по клику получить id элемента (картинки), с которым в дальнейшем можно работать.
Если использовать событие:
`document.addEventListener('click',e => console.log(e.target))`
То значение (включая id) выводится в консоль, но в JS же нет способа обращения к консоли и изъятия данных оттуда?
Как можно иначе получить id?

Comment: Получить куда? Берите `e.target.id` и пихайте куда вам надо

Answer (score 1):

`document.addEventListener('click', e => console.log(e.target));`
Здесь в функции-коллбеке вместо вывода e.target в консоль - выполняйте любые действия с вашим e.target.id

Comment: Как присвоить значение e.target.id моей переменной внутри этого события?

Comment: @YourChoice09 `let мояПеременная = e.target.id;`

Answer (score 0):

ID ещё можно получить, прописав обработчик в коде элемента:

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocfG3.gif?s=256&g=1" id=image onclick='console.log(this.id)' width=150 />
```